# Getting the orignal filename of user control without creating an instance

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

Hi i was wondering if there is a way to get the path of a user control already referenced in a project. ie C:\xxx\yyy\UC1.dll or C:\xxx\yyy\UC2.cs
In VS when you click on the referenced dll under 'project reference' it could show its path. Hence i believe there must be a way.

Thanks in advance

**Update** 
What i am actually trying to get is the path and the version of the user control (dll or uc) used in the program. Although the whole program maybe complie to an exe. But in the exe i would wish to know the properties of the dlls and cs used to build up project.

Comment: If you select a reference and press `F4` or right click and select properties, you can see `Path` of referenced `dll` in the property grid. But it does't have anything to do with user control or .cs file. What's your requirement?

Comment: Hi Reza, i am actually trying to get the path and the version of the user control (dll or uc) used in the program. Although the whole program maybe complie to an exe. But in the exe i would wish to know the properties of the dll and cs used to build the project

Comment: Hi. You can get path for dll but not for .cs file. So for example you can say `SomeControl` is in which dll and what's the path of dll. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi Reza. Yes. Would be nice if i can get the properties of the dll.

Comment: I shared an answer which shows you how to find the dll path and version of  your control.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have a control of type `MyControl`. Then you can find the path and version of dll this way:

```
var type = typeof(MyControl);
var assembly = type.Assembly;
var path = assembly.Location;
var version = assembly.GetName().Version.ToString()
```

Comment: Thanks Reza. I guess that is the only way and i have to hard code certain information in my code.

Comment: You're welcome :) What kind of information for example?

Comment: static string as version in those .cs files and the file name